# Webform comfirmation page token

Tags: 7, webforms

Example I have webform at http://www.example.com/webform. Once I submit the form it will redirect to confirmation page which is http://www.example.com/node/8/done?sid=18&**token**=ggffdgdf7g8df7g89d7fg98df77

May I how to get this token value from database? I had tried md5() for submitted time, but the value is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the `webform.module` file:

```
/**
 * Return the access token for a submission.
 *
 * @param object $submission
 *   The submission object.
 *
 * @return string
 *   The access token for the submission.
 */
function webform_get_submission_access_token($submission) {
  return md5($submission->submitted . $submission->sid . drupal_get_private_key());
}
```

So it's an MD5 hash of a concatenation of the submission date, submission ID and a random private key, set by the webform module.